# Scroll layout containing listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have a `ListView` that contains about 600 elements, right above it I have two spinners that I use to filter the list. Is it possible to make it so that when I start scrolling down the ListView, it first will scroll the entire page to hide the two spinners before it start scrolling the actual ListView.[image]

(The red box is the FrameLayout)

I've sketched out my current layout along with the desired effect. So you start with seeing the two spinners, a single list item which I use as a header for the ListView, and then the ListView itself. When you start scrolling, I want first the spinners to dissapear under the toolbar, and then start the items to scroll.

Is something like this possible? If not, what are some good alternatives to display list filtering controls while also not occupying too much of the screen?

EDIT: 
So I've started experimenting with NestedScrollView, and it sorta works. Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/team_ratings_item" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvTeams"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But with this layout, the ListView appears as just 1 line scrollable. If I set it's height to something high, like 6000dp, it basically does what I want... is there a way to set it's height correctly?

Comment: Hint: Add header view to the height of toolbar + spinners, Determine which is last visible item, at first load, let's say it is 10, when the first visible == 10, then start translating the spinners while first visible position is 10.

Comment: Hi, It seems you were looking for a parallax property https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll, Ill give you a sample in answers w8

Answer (score 1):

Android didn't allowed to have a scrollable view (e.g., ListView) inside another a `ScrollView`.

Recently, the support library has a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html). To solve your issue just replace `ScrollView` by `NestedScrollView` in your XML layout file.

Comment: ListView does not support nested scrolling as a scrolling child before API 21 so this won't work before API 21. You need to use RecyclerView instead.

Comment: @BladeCoder Oh, well thanks. I started trying with NestedScrollView and almost got it to work. Will look into RecyclerView now.

Answer (score 1):

I have **done** same task before 4 months:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"/>

        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="IOS" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#4A9C67" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mListView1;

    private String [] data1 ={"Hiren", "Pratik", "Dhruv", "Narendra", "Piyush", "Priyank"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Your other views

        mListView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

// Your other stuff

        mListView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data1));

        ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(mListView1);
    }


    public static class ListUtils {
        public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView) {
            ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
            if (mListAdapter == null) {
                // when adapter is null
                return;
            }
            int height = 0;
            int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mListView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

**Done**

Comment: Just tried this, I get it up and everything, but it doesn't scroll at all?
My Layout: http://pastebin.com/PQiQHXxu
My Fragment: http://pastebin.com/qdjRGH3w

Answer (score 1):

import Parallax Scroll View https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll in your project

```
<com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:parallax_factor="1.9"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llscroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container_of_the_two_spinner>
      <EditText . . ./>
      <EditText . . ./>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/list_items_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The header"
        android:padding="10dp"  /> 

   //list items here populate from this point with llscroll.addView(); method

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
         >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It looks good in the demo, but it I'll basically have to rebuild all the other ListView functionality? Like I mentioned earlier, Im adding the spinners to filter out items in the ListView, and there are listeners and other things also that I use.

Comment: oh hello, would you like an illusion approach.. what do you think on using ur listview on the lists part but disable its scroll and wraps the contents?? I'm also quite curious :) lemme edit if it works for you

Comment: Yeah, for me the most important part is to keep the two spinners and the ListView. For the rest, anything goes.

Comment: Hi @Limonup here, I never tried it before xD. Kindly try if it's good. As for disabling the listview scrolling. I have other places to check on how

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by following way:

1. Remove scrollview from your layout.
2. Add header view to list view which contains both spinners and list header under one custom xml.
3. Add your list items.

So, when user scrolls list, it will first scroll header which contains 2 spinners and one header and then it will start scrolling list.

If you want to fix header at top and only allow user to scroll items inside it,
you should include pinned section list view where you can pin header and spinner will be scroll up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I wanted:

I moved my two spinners in a LinearLayout, and then I added a scroll listener to the ListView:

```
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int scrolledOffset = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (scrolledOffset != lastVerticalScrollPosition) {
            if(scrolledOffset - lastVerticalScrollPosition > 0) filterSpinners.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else filterSpinners.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lastVerticalScrollPosition = scrolledOffset;
        }
    }
```

Now, when I scroll down, I will hide the LinearLayout and who it again if I scroll up. To make it appear more smooth, I added

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

To parent element of LinearLayout.